# Why my return statement is not showing any output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I was trying to solve the following problem: Draw a star pattern that increases in every step (1st step: 1 star, 2nd step: 2 stars). E.g.

```
*
**
```

I am not sure why my code is not showing any output when I am writing `return`? When I am writing `print`, it is giving me the star output but also giving me `None`. May I know why `return` or `print` are not working properly?  I am using Python 3.7. My code is:

```
def string(inp):
    for i in range (inp):
        return  i*"*"

print (string(5))
```

Comment: Return doesn't print anything. You're returning at the first iteration of the loop instead of printing all the elements or concatenating them

Comment: What you describe doesn't match the code.  "it gives output but prints None" is the behavior of a function that has `print` but no `return`, that is passed to `print(func())`

Comment: It prints a blank because your range starts from zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`range` starts at `0`, and `return` terminates a function, so that means `string` will always return an empty string.

Here's one possible option for getting your expected result:

```
def stars(n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):  # Add one to start and stop
        print(i * "*")  # Print inside the function

stars(2)  # Don't print outside the function
```

Output:

```
*
**
```

---

If you need to print outside the function, you could use a [generator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/231767/4518341):

```
def stars(n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        yield i * "*"  # "yield" is like "return" but can be used more than once

for s in stars(2):
    print(s)  # Print each string that gets yielded

# Or print all at once, using the "splat" unpacking operator
print(*stars(5), sep='\n')
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried the first block of code that you showed. But may I know, why is it printing the result, even if you are not calling the function like this: "print(stars(2))"? Isn't is mandatory to write "print" before calling any function?

Comment: @ktas No, not at all. `print` prints things, doesn't matter where it's called from. In fact `print` is itself a function, and doing `print(print(anything))` is pointless. Maybe you're used to shell scripting, where output is printed instead of being returned?

Answer (score 1):

Using return won't print an output, use something like this:

```
def string(inp):
  for i in range (inp):
    print(i*"*")

string(5)
```

also this will only print 4, if you make it

```
for i in range(inp + 1):
```

It will work as intended,
hope this helps!

Comment: "Using return won't print an output" - that's a confusing way to put it, cause OP wrote it so that the return value of the function would be printed. As well, `range` starts from 0 by default, so you're going to get a blank line. Instead use `range(1, inp+1)`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I tried to get the expected output by writing range(1,inp+1) . Still it is not printing anything.

Answer (score 1):

I will translate the code to plain English, as explicitly as I can:

```
Here are the rules that take a value `inp` and compute the `string` of that `inp`:
    Letting `i` take on each integer value from 0 up to but not including `inp`:
        We are done. The `string` of `inp` is equal to the string '*' repeated `i` times.

Compute the `string` of `5` and display it.
```

Hopefully the problem is evident: we can only be done with a task once, and `i` is equal to 0 at that point, so our computed value is an empty string.

> When I am writing `print`, it is giving me the star output but also giving me `None`

From the described behaviour, I assume that you mean that you tried to replace the word `return` in your code with `print`, giving:

```
def string(inp):
    for i in range (inp):
        print(i*"*")

print (string(5))
```

That produces the triangle, of course, except that

- Since `i` will be equal to 0 the first time through the loop, a blank line is printed; and since `i` will be equal to **4** the **last** time through the loop, there is no `*****` line.
- At the end, `None` is printed, as you describe. This happens because the value computed by `string` is the special value `None`, which is then `print`ed because you asked for it to be printed (`print(string(5))`).

In Python, each call to a function will return a value when it returns, whether or not you use `return` and whether or not you specify a value to `return`. The default is this special `None` value, which is a unique object of its own type. It displays with the text `None` when printed, but is different from a string with that text (in the same way that the integer `5` is different from the string `"5"`).

> May I know why `return` or `print` are not working properly?

They are working exactly as designed. `return` specifies the result of calling the function, and can only happen once per function, and does not cause anything to be displayed. `print` displays what it is given.

If you wish to `return` multiple values from a call, then you need to work around that restriction - either by using a *generator* instead (as in @MadPhysicist's or @wjandrea's answers), or by using some single, structured datum that contains all those values (for example, a list, or a tuple).

Answer (score -1):

A a re-entrant function that preserves state between calls is a generator. To make a generator function, change the keyword `return` to `yield`:

```
def string(n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield (i + 1) * '*'
```

Calling this version of `string` will return a generator that yields a new line of your desired output at each iteration.

To print:

```
for line in string(5):
    print(line)
```

To print all at once:

```
print('\n'.join(string(5)))
```